# Error in confusionMatrix.default(data.testTree, testing$money.gain) : the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Tags: r, testing, levels, rpart

No, because when you run `caret::confusionMatrix (data.testTree, testing $ money.gain)` tells me this: the data can not have any more than the reference levels.

I have run these commands:

```
cvControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv" number = 10, repeats = 5)
tree.rpart <- caret::train(form.in,data=training,method="rpart",
    metric="money.gain",trControl=cvControl)
```

For the whole test run the following command:

```
testing <- testing[complete.cases(testing),]
data.testTree <- caret::predict.train(tree.rpart, NewData = testing)
```

Now we have to finalize the results obtained with the confusion matrix:

```
caret::confusionMatrix(data.testTree, testing$money.gain)

identical (levels(testing$money.gain), levels(testing$money.gain))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataTest.tree object might not contain your predicted classes since the option to caret::predict.train function is 'newdata' not 'NewData' like you have it. Try changing that line to:

> dataTest.tree <- caret::predict.train(tree.part, newdata = testing)

Also, in the line after that, the identical function is comparing the same thing and will always return a TRUE result. I'm assuming you wanted to compare the result of the predict function and the test data set response levels. I bet if you changed that, the result of that line will be a FALSE.